# 15k mile oil filter

Tags: oil, oil-filter

I have been using M1 in my jeep since I bought it with 22k miles on it.  I now have 31k and i am thinking about getting M1 Extended Performance which is supposed to last 15k miles between oil changes.

Is there an oil filter that I could trust to last 15k miles?  Or should I just stick with normal oil?

Comment: if regularly offroading particularly in dusty conditions I change mine every 10,000
miles-twice as often in a diesel where contamination is a big issue

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of running 15k miles between changes myself (while the oil may be stable that long, you're also circulating all the contaminants that your oil picks up much longer), but if you choose to do so, I'd use the matching oil filter.  If M1 Extended Performance oil is what you choose, use the M1 Extended Performance oil filter that goes along with it.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Brian either use the M1 Extended Perf oil filter or maybe look at the AMSOIL Ea oil filters which I use and are quite good. I change my oil once a year with that.

Also you might want to look into bypass oil filters. Amsoil sells these but im sure you can get them elsewhere as well basically what it does is run 15% of the oil through a much finer filter to catch the finest of particles this can extend your drain intervals quite a bit with premium oil. All the oil will be filtered every 5-10 minutes so it should collect just about all the free floating debris in the oil. You can then change this filter either every change or every other change depending on how big of a filter you get and how long you wait between changes.

I bought a bypass filter kit but haven't found the time to install it yet...